# Naturally improve eyesight

Tags: eye, ophthalmology

Is there a possibility to improve the deteriorating eyesight naturally? If yes, how is it possible? If the eye sight continues to get worse, is there a chance of losing eyesight completely?

Comment: am asking about improving eyesight naturally, in what way glasses can be considered as natural?

Comment: It just seems like glasses are very common and was wondering why they weren't an option.

Comment: its just common and people tend to wear that . that doesn't make glasses as an normal option. and it doesn't improve eyesight it just makes you see the world normally with adjusting its power to the power of your eyesight .

Comment: Tell me your your age and in what way your eye sight is deteriorating? . Is your power increasing

Comment: its not about me i have a cousin of mine whose eye sight is deteriorating and the power is increasing with time. is their any way to stop it get more worse. can be bettered by any way that is natural.

Comment: I've heard that past a certain age (40?) your eyesight naturally starts improving.

Comment: @akshay I need age of your cousin to answer question and does he has problem with seeing  distant vision or near vision?

Comment: @umeshkrishna his age is 22 he has a problem with seeing distant vision

Comment: "Deteriorating eyesight" can mean anything from common vision correction to myopia, cataracts, glaucoma, physical injuries, neurological causes, or anything that covers many diverse fields. I suspect you're asking if there are any lifestyle/health choices you  can make to avoid/reduce the need for glasses... but this question is all over the place and users are just guessing. I can't fix this thread at this point. If you can get really specific about what condition you are trying to correct and what type of answers you are looking for, feel free to try again. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ps:myopia is condition your cousin is having most likely.

children's bodies grow, so do the eyes, which may cause a gradual increase in myopia. And just as bodily growth can be in uneven spurts, the changes in myopia may be similarly uneven. During adolescence, the change can be rather rapid and require a new, thicker eyeglass correction more than once a year, but when body growth slows or stops (usually by age 18), the myopia tends to stabilize. There is normally no reason to worry about the frequent changes in lens correction that occur during adolescence. Almost never is there any real danger to eyesight, and vision can almost always be corrected to 20/20 or better with eyeglasses or contact lenses.

Note: There is an extremely rare type of myopia, called malignant progressive myopia, which is a serious condition and leads to gradual structural damage to the eye. This type needs regular clinical evaluation. It is not related to ordinary myopia and does not develop from ordinary myopia.

1. For your cousin, it may be the correct time for his eyeball to stop growing . Ask him to do check up regularly.
2. If it still continues, ask him to check his doctor.
3. Balanced diet is recommended to prevent further deteriorating of myopia aka distant vision problem, esp vit A.
4. It is an irreversible process, you can't bring his power back to normal naturally
5. But you can go for lasik surgery, but I don't recommend it personally. .  It has its own line of complications

Comment: "heredity, stress, watching television or such monitor regularly and for longer duration or closely. " . This is false belief /myth . . Reference http://www.triadpublishing.com/eyecarereports/myopia-book.shtml